# how to get a static property from a list of class

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have class like this :

```
public class StaticProvider
{
    public static int ID_DR;
    public static string CorporateName;
    public static string Logo;
    public static string Address;
    public static string Suite;
    public static string City;
    public static string State;
    public static Decimal Zip;
    public static string Phone;
    public static string Facebook;
    public static string Twitter;
    public static string Doctor;
    public static string Password;
    public static string Email;
    public static string OfficeWebLink_URL;
    public string Provider_Name;
    public int Provider_id;
}
```

and i have a return type like this : `List<StaticProvider> Lst= new List<StaticProvider>()` , 
PROBLEM IS HERE :
how can i get Static Property from  My List

For Exaple i wanna get `StaticProvider.Address`

Answer (score 3):

StaticProvider.Logo. It does not matter what you store in list.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've misunderstood the way that static variables work. Assuming your class is meant to represent some sort of contact, your variables *shouldn't* be static to start with. They should be *instance* variables.

Currently, given two instances of `StaticProvider`, you can have two different `Provider_id` values, but you can't have two different passwords, addresses etc - because there's just *one* `Password` field which is for the type itself, rather than any specific instance of the type.

Additionally, it would be better to use *properties* rather than public fields - separate the public API of your type from how you happen to store the data within the type. Finally, follow .NET naming conventions (get rid of the underscores) and give your class a more meaningful name. For example:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string CorporateName { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    ...
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
}
```

It's not really clear what the "provider" is at all, to be honest. Perhaps you actually want *two* classes here:

```
public class ContactProvider
{
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }

    public Contact LoadContact(int contactId)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string CorporateName { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    // No need for provider properies, or possibly one of type ContactProvider
}
```

Comment: @AlirezaMassali: No, because that's not a meaningful *concept*. A static property isn't associated with a particular instance - it's associated with the type itself.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that static members belongs to the class / type and not to the instance - this is why you cannot access the property of the instances.

To access the field on an instance of the `StaticProvider` class, you need to remove the `static` keyword. That would make the field belong to an instance instead, and you will be good to go.

Example:

```
public class StaticProvider
{
    ...
    public string Address;
    ...
}
```

As a general comment, I believe it is much better to use public properties rather than public fields. With properties you can encapsulate the access to the actual fields which stores the values. In that way, you will have much better control on what can be assigned to the field and, as Jon Skeet says, you also separates the public "API" from how the data is stored - which is a good point.

Comment: I know why i cant access them , But how to access the is Problem , is there any Idea

Comment: @AlirezaMassali: No, I suspect you don't fully understand the problem yet. Do you understand that your objects don't each have an address? It would really help if you'd give more context in the question.